# Latex, Netbib, Mendeley, Harvard style and URL referencing issues

Tags: latex, overleaf, mendeley

I am new to latex and am trying to sort out my process for referencing.

I use the mendeley webplugin to capture the references I need. This is then exported as a .bib file, uploaded via google drive, and imported into Overleaf for use in latex. I need to use the Harvard referencing style and as such I have this code.

```
%%%%%% Referencing %%%%%%
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
```

This is working, I have to manually refresh the uploaded .bib when a new reference is added but that's no big deal. The issue comes when I try and reference a website. I know referencing websites is frowned upon however this is a Gov site :).

my standard in-text citations look like \citet{citationkey} and \citep{citationkey} however, when I try this with a URL things get janky, output appears as "Mai" with a reference in the bibliography:

```
Commercial Fishing Historical Landings Data: Maine Department of Marine Resources. URL https:
95 //www.maine.gov/dmr/commercial-fishing/landings/historical-data.html."
```

I looked back and in Mendeley my reference is set as:
Type - Webpage
Title - Commercial Fishing Historical Landings Data: Maine Department of Marine Resources
Citation key - MaineFisheries2021
Date Accessed - 2021-11-24
URL https://www.maine.gov/dmr/commercial-fishing/landings/historical-data.html

So the information is there. I opened the .bib file to confirm the structure seemed ok:

```
@misc{MaineFisheries2021,
title = {{Commercial Fishing Historical Landings Data: Maine Department of Marine Resources}},
url = {https://www.maine.gov/dmr/commercial-fishing/landings/historical-data.html},
urldate = {2021-11-24}
}
```

So as far as I can see the data is being captured, stored in Mendeley and exported to the .bib as intended. That leaves the actual latex integration as the issue however I have no idea how to even peel back the netbib stuff.

*edit*

The example given by the referencing style sheet is:
in-text (Google, 2020),
Reference Template Author surname, initial. (Year) Page Title. Available at: URL (Accessed: Day Month Year). and the example for the reference, Google (2020) Google terms of service. Available at: https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=en-US (Accessed: 11 May 2020).

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre] and also add how else you want your website to be referenced if not with `Mai`?

Comment: The example given by the referencing style sheet is: in-text (Google, 2020), `Reference Template Author surname, initial. (Year) Page Title. Available at: URL (Accessed: Day Month Year).` and the example for the reference, `Google (2020) Google terms of service. Available at: https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=en-US (Accessed: 11 May 2020).`

Comment: That for adding the desired result, but can you also add a compilable [mre]?